# Boolean value not changing in for loop

Tags: c++

I have a for loop that searches through a vector for an object "Book".  If the *refBook* is in the vector, it is supposed to return true.  If not, then false.

```
int has = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < mBooks.size()-1; i++) {
    if (mBooks.at(i) == refBook) {
        has = 1;
        cout << "Has book " << has << endl;
    };
};

return has;
```

It goes through the loop correctly and will print the cout statement if the Book is in the vector.  However, it still returns 0.  If *has = 1;* instead, then it will return 1.  It never changes its value if the Book is in the vector.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the code you're looking for (waves hand in a Jedi-like manner).

Short of memory corruption, that function, as it stands now, *will* return `1` if the statement is printed.

So your problem probably lies elsewhere.

I will give *one* bit of advice: if you're just looking to see if the book is in there, there's *no* need to keep looking once you've found it. And you should check the *entire* vector, at the moment you're skipping the last item. You would be better off with something like:

```
int hasBook (TBook &refBook) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mBooks.size(); i++) {
        if (mBooks.at(i) == refBook) {
            cout << "Has book " << refBook << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing, you don't need a closing semi-colon after the closing parentheses on the 'if' block or the 'for' block. Next thing, I suspect the problem may be:

```
(int i = 0; i < mBooks.size()-1; i++)
```

See that minus 1? That means that you're not going to check the last item in the vector. If the book is the last item in the vector, you won't pick it up! [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) diagram gives a nice little summation of the problem I believed you've come up against.

Try this instead:

```
int has = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < mBooks.size(); i++)
{
    if (mBooks.at(i) == refBook)
    {
        has = 1;
        cout << "Has book " << has << endl;
    }
}

return has;
```

Here are a few more tips for you. C++ has a built-in boolean type, bool, which you can use instead of an integer, to signal 'true' and 'false' (which are keywords!). Vectors can also be indexed like native arrays too, so you can the []'s instead of 'at'. So, here's a slightly more C++'ish version of your code:

```
bool has = false;

for (int i = 0; i < mBooks.size(); i++)
{
    if (mBooks[i] == refBook)
    {
        has = true;
        cout << "Has book " << has << endl;
    }
}

return has;
```

One final suggestion, which is a bit more advanced, is to use the new C++11 'range for' syntax, which can be used on vectors and lists and the like. I'm also going to introduce the 'auto' and 'break' keywords, which I recommend you familiarise yourself with:

```
bool has = false;

for (auto& book : mBooks)
{
    if (book == refBook)
    {
        has = true;
        cout << "Has book " << has << endl;
        break;
    }
}

return has;
```

Finally, it would be worthwhile looking at std::find function (**edit: I see someone else has raised this**) which isprovided for situations just like this.

Comment: Well spotted Barry :).

Answer (score 3):

I'll just throw out that this is precisely what [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) exists for:

```
bool has = (std::find(mBooks.begin(), mBooks.end(), refBook) != mBooks.end());
```

It's easy to make mistakes when writing loops (such as stopping one iteration short) - which is why sometimes it can be good to try to avoid writing them in the first place.

Comment: Could you mention `std::any_of`?

Comment: @NickyC No. `any_of` takes a predicate. `find` is exactly the correct algorithm to use here. Even in C++11, I would never use `any_of` here.